# Ancient Art of DOS Batch Files

Tags: file, batch-file, dos

Years ago I had a document titled "The Ancient Art of DOS Batch Files".  It was posted on the internet and widely distributed.  Recently, I have been unable to find my copy of it - digital or otherwise - and every search I've done points me to a site that no longer exists (http://gatsby.tafe.tas.edu.au/batch/).

Can anyone point me to where I can get a copy of this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: As an alternative, I find the site [ss64.com/nt](http://ss64.com/nt/) very useful.  It's my CMD bible.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a nice reference.  The document I'm looking for is more like a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

archive.org  is your lifesaver. You can even see that there was a redirect :)

HTH

[1] `http://wayback.archive.org/web/*/http://gatsby.tafe.tas.edu.au/*`

Answer (score 0):

I recently uncovered my original copy of this document while cleaning out some boxes in my home office. I'm in the process of reproducing it for others who may be looking for it.

https://github.com/scottoffen/TheAncientArtOfDOSBatchFiles